# Counter-example to the proposition that for any $\alpha>0,$ every large subset of natural numbers has a convex subsequence that sums to $\alpha.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples

> Proposition: Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset \mathbb{N}$ be a
> strictly increasing sequence of positive integers that is large i.e.
> $\displaystyle\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{a_n}$ diverges. Let
> $\alpha > 0.$ Then there is a convex subsequence $(a_{k_n})_{n\in
>  \mathbb{N}}$ of $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that
> $\displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{a_{k_n}}\ = \alpha.$
>
> Convex means $$ a_2 - a_1 \leq a_3 - a_2 \leq a_4 - a_3 \leq \ldots .
>  $$

I want to check if the following sequence is a counter-example:

$a_1 = 9, a_2 = 10,\ a_3 = 90, a_4 = 91, \ldots, a_{13} = 100,\ a_{14} = 900, a_{15} = 901, \ldots, a_{114} = 1000,\ a_{115} = 9000,\ldots .$

We have: $\displaystyle\sum \frac{1}{a_n} \approx \left(\ln \frac{10}{9} \right)\cdot \infty \approx \left(\frac{1}{9}\right)\cdot\infty = \infty.$

But the maximum possible value of $\displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{a_{k_n}}\ $ if $(a_{k_n})$ is convex, is $\ \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{90} + \frac{1}{900} + \frac{1}{9000} + \ldots = \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{9} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{100} + \frac{1}{1000} + \ldots \right) = \frac{1}{10} + \frac{10}{81} = 0.223\ldots. $

So no convex subsequence of this $(a_n)$ can sum to $0.225,$ for example.

I would like to check if my counter-example is correct for the reasoning I have provided.

Comment: What does $a_n = \mathbb{N} \bigcap\left( [9,10] \cup [90, 100] \cup [900,1000] \cup [9000, 10000] \cup \ldots \right)$ mean?

Comment: @geetha290krm You're right, I was abusing notation. I've edited that part accordingly.

Comment: Where does that proposition come from?

Comment: I came up with it myself. Just want to know more about sequences and series, as I'm working on Erdos conjecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your counterexample is good. However, as a nitpick, rather than
$$\displaystyle\sum \frac{1}{a_n} \approx \left(\ln \frac{10}{9} \right)\cdot \infty \approx \left(\frac{1}{9}\right)\cdot\infty = \infty$$

I would prefer to write something to the effect of
$$\sum_{k=1}^{10^n}\frac1{a_k}>\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{10}=\frac n{10}\to\infty\;\text{as}\;n\to\infty.$$

Comment: Sure, I was abusing notation.